# Joining data from different xpath with xslt

Tags: xslt

I'm trying to do an xml trasformation with XSLT. I have the following xml:

```
<myxml>
<dataType1>
    <value1>
        A1
    </value1>
    <value2>
        A2
    </value2>
</dataType1>
<dataType1>
    <value1>
        B1
    </value1>
    <value2>
        B2
    </value2>
</dataType1>
<dataType2>
    <value1>
        A1
    </value1>
    <value3>
        A3
    </value3>
</dataType2>
<dataType2>
    <value1>
        B1
    </value1>
    <value3>
        B3
    </value3>
</dataType2>
```

each datatype2 has an element value1 that is a foreign key in the datatype2 so then I have to map this data based on the value1.

If exists a dataType1 with value1=A1 and a dataType2 with a value1=A1 then I have to create an xml with the values of value2 and value3 so the result will be the following:

```
<resultxml>
<data>
    <value2>
        A2
    </value2>
    <value3>
        A3
    </value3>
</data>
<data>
    <value2>
        B2
    </value2>
    <value3>
        B3
    </value3>
</data>
```

I thought about creating dynamically the variables while reading the dataType1 and then calling them when reading the datatype2 but as I read on some forum that is not possible so my question is: is possible to do what I explained? if yes which is the approach I have to follow (examples are welcome)

thanks in advance

Comment: Is this a 1:1 relation? If there is more than one dataType2 with corresponding value1, what will happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:key name="kType1" match="dataType1" use="normalize-space(value1)"/>

 <xsl:template match="dataType2[key('kType1', normalize-space(value1))]">
     <data>
       <value2>
         <xsl:value-of select="key('kType1', normalize-space(value1))/value2"/>
       </value2>
       <xsl:copy-of select="value3"/>
     </data>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<myxml>
    <dataType1>
        <value1>
        A1
        </value1>
        <value2>
        A2
        </value2>
    </dataType1>
    <dataType1>
        <value1>
        B1
        </value1>
        <value2>
        B2
        </value2>
    </dataType1>
    <dataType2>
        <value1>
        A1
        </value1>
        <value3>
        A3
        </value3>
    </dataType2>
    <dataType2>
        <value1>
        B1
        </value1>
        <value3>
        B3
        </value3>
    </dataType2>
</myxml>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<data>
   <value2>
        A2
   </value2>
   <value3>
        A3
   </value3>
</data>
<data>
   <value2>
        B2
   </value2>
   <value3>
        B3
   </value3>
</data>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an XSLT 2.0 stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="2.0">

  <xsl:key name="k1" match="dataType2" use="normalize-space(value1)"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* , node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="dataType1[key('k1', value1)]">
    <data>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node() except value1, key('k1', normalize-space(value1))/*[not(self::value1)]"/>
    </data>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="dataType1[not(key('k1', normalize-space(value1)))] | dataType2"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When above stylesheet is applied on the input

```
<myxml>
<dataType1>
    <value1>
        A1
    </value1>
    <value2>
        A2
    </value2>
</dataType1>
<dataType1>
    <value1>
        B1
    </value1>
    <value2>
        B2
    </value2>
</dataType1>
<dataType2>
    <value1>
        A1
    </value1>
    <value3>
        A3
    </value3>
</dataType2>
<dataType2>
    <value1>
        B1
    </value1>
    <value3>
        B3
    </value3>
</dataType2>
</myxml>
```

with Saxon 9.4 then the result is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><myxml>
<dataType1>
    <value1>
        A1
    </value1>
    <value2>
        A2
    </value2>
</dataType1>
<dataType1>
    <value1>
        B1
    </value1>
    <value2>
        B2
    </value2>
</dataType1>


</myxml>
```

With XSLT 1.0 you can't use a key inside of a match pattern so some more code is needed, I will add a sample later.

[edit]
Here is an XSLT 1.0 stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="1.0">

  <xsl:key name="k1" match="dataType2" use="normalize-space(value1)"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="dataType1">
    <xsl:variable name="refs" select="key('k1', normalize-space(value1))"/>
    <xsl:if test="$refs">
      <data>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()[not(self::value1)] | $refs/*[not(self::value1)]"/>
      </data>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="dataType2"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1):

my proposal

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="no" />
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <resultxml>
            <xsl:for-each select="/myxml/dataType1">
                <xsl:variable name="fk" select="value1" />
                <data>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="value2" />
                    <xsl:copy-of select="/myxml/dataType2[value1 = $fk]/value3" />
                </data>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </resultxml>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```